# Dual Boot unistallation

Tags: dual-boot

My system is in Dual boot 1) Ubuntu 2) Windows 8.
How can I uninstall Windows8
If I uninstall Windows8 would it affect my other partitions (Drive D,E).

Comment: Since `Drive D` and `Drive E` are Windows names, I would guess they would vanish with Windows.

Comment: If you have other NTFS partitions, you either need Windows or a Windows repair disk. NTFS will need chkdsk and defrag which you can only do from Windows. If totally uninstalling Windows best to backup all data, and reformat all partitions (which will erase all data). Then restore data to new ext4 formatted partitions.

Answer (score 1):

To "uninstall" Windows, simply format its partition. You can use various tools for that. Probably `gparted` would be easiest for you.

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure to copy the data which you want to preserve. Userspace by default is located in `C:\Users\<Username>`.

Afterwards, it is as simple as running `# update-grub`.
Your other partitions will not be affected, however you need to make sure to mount them. This may include editing the `/etc/fstab` file accordingly.
Linux will have no problem with NTFS (assuming that's the filesystem you use).